# MongoDB 3.2 to 3.6 Upgradation Performance/Slowness issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have upgraded the MongoDB server from 3.2 to 3.6.

The scenario is like previously we were having 3.4 setup installed on Server DB01 and the feature compatibility was 3.2 running. we have done upgradation to our DB01 server of 800 GB data set to 3.2 > 3.4 > 3.6 in one the Go. after doing this Upgradation we faced Performance issues of performance on PROD App. but same Application is running on 3.6 properly on as UAT other PROD servers smoothly on DB04.

Now we have to the Downgrade of the server to back on 3.2 version. and monitoring continually.

below are the points which we have faced in details:

1. DB01 was on the 3.2 compatibility version and we have upgraded it to 3.6 compatibility version.
2. after this we faced that indexes were starting from backend continuously so that issue we closed with NoRetryBuildIndex parameter.
3. Then next day we faced Performance/Slowness issue from DB server queries were taking time for fetching data, for this we have increased the cache size from 5 GB to 10 GB.
4. For one week the slowness was not found but after one week on Monday slowness issue had come.
5. we are suspecting the drivers will be the issue.

Guys pls help into this what do you think from your perspective.

Regards,
Yogesh J.

Comment: If the indexes didn't build, that would seriously hurt performance.

Comment: Actually the index build creation was mentioned in code base so comment that as well and we add noRetryBuildIndex as well. Cause it was getting build and after killing that again was get building from start.